# wp enqueue, how to prevent duplication when same script is registered with different handles

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I read that wp enqueue prevents duplicate script to be loaded. But, what happens when same script ( say bootstrap.js) is loaded by 2 different plugins with 2 different handles using wp enqueue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS/CSS Duplication by itself is not bad. It makes the HTML a little bigger nut the browser should in most cases cache the first request and not serve the second one (most cases === unless it is a very badly configured server)

The real problem with duplication is trying to load two different versions of the same file (say two different versions of jQuery), and this is what the API helps to solve by providing a handle to the version which already exists as part of core.

The best thing in your case is to probably think again why do you even need bootstrap in a plugin, why the admin CSS and JS is not enough for you.

Comment: I don't want to use bootstrap in admin. I just want to use bootstrapp pop up in short code of plugin

Comment: then just don't, as you are likely to have conflicts with bootstrap based themes. In addition it doesn't make much sense to add a full framework just for a popup.

Comment: I agree with you. Do you have any suggestions for good light weight pop js plugin for wp front end

Comment: Popup is very easy, just need to absolute position a div which is usually hidden and give some opacitiy to the page. I think it takes about 20 lines of JS and another 30 CSS to do it, just google for lighbox effects and you will probably find several examples

Answer (score 0):

In general:

1. Only load the functionality you need in specific plugin.
2. Use noConflict mode (typically available in serious libs) right after you load your copy.

All of this works quite fine with Bootstrap (they used to have issues with noConflict implementation, but they have worked kinks out).

For example in my Laps plugin I compile my JS file from three parts:

1. Tooltip component of Bootstrap.
2. noConflict directive, moving tooltip to my own name.
3. My actual code, setting up tooltips via my own name.

WP doesn't quite have convenient way to output JS *right after* queued script, so combining it into single file is most reliable.

```
// tooltip source here

jQuery.fn.lapstooltip = jQuery.fn.tooltip.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".laps-timeline .event").lapstooltip({
        container: '#wpadminbar',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html     : true,
        animation: false
    });
});
```

See [full source](https://github.com/Rarst/laps/blob/master/js/laps.js).

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Rarst, its equally helpful  and informative as Mark s answer. But this forum allows only one to be accepted.